# Adding a comma and two decimal places

Tags: awk

I am trying to add comma and decimal places in the given numbers. For e.g.

```
addcomma.txt
12345
34534534534
234325
```

Expected:

```
12,345.00
34,53,45,34,534.00
2,34,325.00
```

This result is close. But instead of adding a comma before, it adds the comma after the first 3 digits.

```
12345                   123,45.00
34534534534    345,34,53,45,34.00
234325                23,43,25.00
```

The code (from google):

```
awk '{ printf ("%-12s %20s\n", $0, addcomma($0)) }
function addcomma(x, num) {
if (x < 0)
return "-" addcomma(-x)
num = sprintf("%.2f", x) 
while (num ~ /[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/)
sub(/[0-9][0-9)[0-9][,.]/, ",&", num)
return num
}' addcomma.txt
```

I do not want to change or install locale for the sake of portability of script.

Comment: You've **misspelled** the second `[0-9]`in the `sub` call as `[0-9)`. As a result you match 3 charlists not 4: first `0-9` and second `0-9)[0-9` which for your input data is equivalent to just `0-9` and third `,.`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I guess OP copy/pasted from one of those poor OCR rips of [The AWK Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_AWK_Programming_Language) you see on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you fix the `[0-9)` vs `[0-9]` typo in the script in your question you'll see it is designed to add thousands separators every 3 digits (`1,000,000`) from the right, not lakh separators every 2 digits left of the right-most 3 digits (`10,00,000`).

Ideally you'd just set the locale to a country code that supports that format and then print it as a floating point number, e.g.:

```
$ LC_ALL="as_IN" awk '{printf "%\0470.2f\n", $0}' addcomma.txt
12,345.00
34,53,45,34,534.00
2,34,325.00
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Format-Modifiers for more info on that `printf` statement and be aware I'm using [`\047` as a `'` character](http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote) so `"%\0470.2f\n"` is equivalent to `"%'0.2f\n"`.

To see which locales use that format on your machine you can run:

```
$ for LC_ALL in $(locale -a | sort); do LC_ALL="$LC_ALL" awk 'BEGIN{printf "%s -> %\0470.2f\n", ENVIRON["LC_ALL"], 111111 }'; done | grep ',11,'
as_IN -> 1,11,111.00
as_IN.utf8 -> 1,11,111.00
bn_BD -> 1,11,111.00
bn_BD.utf8 -> 1,11,111.00
bn_IN -> 1,11,111.00
bn_IN.utf8 -> 1,11,111.00
...
```

If, as you've now added to your question, you can't use the appropriate locale, then this will work in any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ printf "%-12s %20s\n", $0, addcomma($0) }

function addcomma(old,  lgth,head,tail,new) {
    if ( old < 0 ) {
        new = "-" addcomma(-old)
    }
    else {
        old  = sprintf("%.2f",old)
        head = substr(old,1,length(old)-6)
        lgth = length(head)
        tail = substr(old,lgth+1)
        head = (lgth % 2 ? "0" : "") head
        gsub(/../,"&,",head)
        sub(/^0/,"",head)
        new = head tail
    }
    return new
}
```

e.g. given this input file to test more of the functionality:

```
$ cat addcomma.txt
1
12
123
1234
12345
34534534534
234325
12345.732
-1
-12
-123
-1234
-12345
-34534534534
-234325
-12345.732
```

it will produce this output:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk addcomma.txt
1                            1.00
12                          12.00
123                        123.00
1234                     1,234.00
12345                   12,345.00
34534534534    34,53,45,34,534.00
234325                2,34,325.00
12345.732               12,345.73
-1                          -1.00
-12                        -12.00
-123                      -123.00
-1234                   -1,234.00
-12345                 -12,345.00
-34534534534  -34,53,45,34,534.00
-234325              -2,34,325.00
-12345.732             -12,345.73
```

which is the same as using an appropriate locale so I assume that's the expected output for that input:

```
$ LC_ALL="as_IN" awk '{ new=sprintf("%\0470.2f", $0); printf "%-12s %20s\n", $0, new }' addcomma.txt
1                            1.00
12                          12.00
123                        123.00
1234                     1,234.00
12345                   12,345.00
34534534534    34,53,45,34,534.00
234325                2,34,325.00
12345.732               12,345.73
-1                          -1.00
-12                        -12.00
-123                      -123.00
-1234                   -1,234.00
-12345                 -12,345.00
-34534534534  -34,53,45,34,534.00
-234325              -2,34,325.00
-12345.732             -12,345.73
```